# How to label points in a scatter plot?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I've tried using the built-in scatter plot chart and the Google scatter plot gadget. I haven't been able to figure out how to get either one to allow me to label the points in the chart. I have data like the following:

```
| Name1 | 36 | 1 | 
| Name2 | 22 | 3 |
| Name3 | 21 | 6 |
| Name4 |  4 | 2 |
| Name5 |  8 | 2 |
```

How do I label the point at (8,2) on the scatter plot as `Name5`, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [cell_object](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#cell_object) instead of just a value worked for me

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [ {v: 36, f: 'Name1 - 36'}, 1],
          [ {v: 22, f: 'Name2 - 22'}, 3],
          [ {v: 21, f: 'Name3 - 21'}, 6],
          [ {v: 4, f: 'Name4 - 4'}, 2],
          [ {v: 8, f: 'Name5 - 8'}, 2]
        ]);
```

Comment: that's using the api, right?  How would I do that within my google docs spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes that is using the api.  Using a google docs spreadsheet the only way I can work out how is by using a Bubble chart and formatting like you have in the questions

Comment: The bubble chart is new since I asked this question.  I was able to add it to my chart and it worked alright. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 15):

Today's Google announced that now it's possible to add data labels.

For the data included in the question,

1. Move the first column to the rightmost position.

   ```
    | A | B |  C   |
   -+---+---+------+
   1| 36|  1|Name1 |
   2| 22|  3|Name2 |
   3| 21|  6|Name3 |
   4|  4|  2|Name4 |
   5|  8|  2|Name5 |
   ```

   **Note**: Labels should be text. If the labels are numbers, dates, times, durations convert them to text. For this we could use [TO_TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en), [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en), to add an `'` as prefix or set the cell formatting to text.
2. Then insert the chart and choose the scatter plot chart.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bboygA0H9r0OgjAF7y4ixdJOqSf2rbHoXAy204lFBaE/edit?usp=sharing)

NOTE: If you want to play with the example please make a copy instead to ask permission to edit it. To make a copy click on File > Make a copy.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. If it does not work for you right away you have to deselect and select the scatter plot in the overview.

Comment: Is there a way to only show labels for select points?

Comment: @DmitryB. That should be posted as a question. See [ask].

Comment: Heads up! If the label column is numerical (as with house numbers), it needs to be changed into a string. Otherwise it will try to plot that data.

Comment: Can I edit the chart to achieve this effect? I don't want to shift my columns around arbitrarily just to get a certain plot to work (I've got a large sheet with lots of columns and labels in column A).

Comment: I'm trying the example (which looks great), but can not reproduce the results. I have tried selecting the data, then Insert -> Chart (which defaults to trying to give me a column chart).

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the procedure to get to Ruben's chart explicit, here are the steps I took:

- in the chart editor --> Setup go down to your series and click on the 3 dots next to your series.
- choose add labels. By default it will take the X-axis. [image]
- But it you click on the small grid icon, you can choose the range for the labels.
  [image]
  [image]
- then you get the result
  [image]